# Receiving data via Bluetooth and viewing it on app screen

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently building an application that will connect to a device via bluetooth and receive data from it. Currently i am able to connect with the paired devices, but can't seem to find any good resources on how to receive data from that device. I have attached 2 images of the application, the first one; is the main menu. In there you'll see a button that says "connect to TANGO", in which i have put in all the code below. That allows me to connect to any paired devices. Also in the main menu, there's a "Translate" button, and that's were i am trying to receive data in, and view them, but so far i haven't been able to do so.

Here's the code for the "connect to TANGO" connection.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class connection extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
    ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);

         b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
         b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
         b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

         BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
         lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

public void on(View v){
    if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void off(View v){
if (BA.disable());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public  void visible(View v){
    Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
}


public void list(View v){
    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

[image: main_menu]

[image: bluetooth_discovery]

Answer (score 0):

When you have a reference to a paired BluetoothDevice you need to create a socket and listen to it. Simplified example follows:

**Create a BluetoothSocket and connect to it:**

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(<your-device>.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
socket.connect();
```

**Listen to the socket (Get data from the device)**

```
InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
while (inStream.available() > 0) {
    inStream.read(); // <-- data from device
}
```

**Write to the socket (Send data to the device)**

```
OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = <some-data>
outStream.write(bytes);
```

For more detailed information, with examples, see [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the help. i just have one more question, since i connect to the bluetooth in "connect to TANGO" activity; am i able to receive and view the data in the "Translate" activity?? or everything has to be in the same .java file ??

Comment: @KamelHamdan I would put the bluetooth reading and writing in its own Thread with callbacks (e.g some Observer pattern) to where the data should be used. Take a look at the `ConnectedThread` example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) for how to create the Thread (or parts of it). Information about callback-patterns [here](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/) (you need to modify this for your needs, but is shows the general idea)

Answer (score 0):

@krekle would this code work.

```
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
}

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private android.os.Handler mHandler;

    public display (BluetoothSocket socket, Handler mHandler) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

i only had to change "ConnectThread" to "display" and "Thread" to "AppCompatActivity" just to match with the activities that i already made before.